# Crystal report can call or run another report after finished like chain reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi I tried to link or call another report, but i don't know how because i need to call that report after report finished like chain report not like subreport, I need to print a form but form first page has come information and second copy or page is lite different for i think  must be to call after finished the report chain to another report could be possible that...

I tried to put link report on foot of report but don't show me or not call the report....

some body can help me or ide how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Insert a subreport.

Option 2: Use a 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tool to allow a batch file to call the 2 reports and export/print them one after the other. That would also allow you to use different paper trays, in case that is part of the challenge. Ken Hamady maintains a listing of 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).